# Stream 100MB+ file from AWS Cloud to the Thing using AWS IoT

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

So here is the scenario. We have a IoT device/thing which upon setting up need some drivers and firmware. Some files are huge in size like 100MB+ and in those cases instead of sending the data in one go, we would like stream the data from the AWS Cloud to the THING.

I have been looking for ways to do it, and there is an option like IoT Streaming service, but there is no basic code documentation on how to do it in Nodejs. I'm a newbie with nodejs and IoT stuff so if someone can point me towards some help documentation or sites to see how to do it, that would be great!

Using the below code, I cannot transfer more than 10MB.

```
iot.createStream(params, function (err, data) {
   if (err) return err;
   return data;
})
```

Error that we are getting:

File size 221413376 of stream file 0 in stream  exceeds the file size limit

Params for createStream:

````
    files: [ /* required */
      {
        fileId: 0,
        s3Location: {
          bucket: bucket, /* required */
          key: params.s3key
        }
      }
    ],
    roleArn: config.jobRoleARN, /* required */
    streamId: uuidv1(), /* required */
   description: 'Get file as Stream'
  }```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This documentation from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/iot-core.html#limits-streaming-service) suggests that the maximum file size for streaming is 24MB. If that's the case, you may need to try and break up the file into smaller pieces or see if it can be compressed to a reasonable size (or both).

Only additional note: depending on what you're doing with the returned data, you might want to utilize pipes and transform/writable streams to take advantage of [node's backpressure handling mechanisms](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/), like below:

```
const request = iot.createStream(params);
const out = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/outfile.jpg');

request.createReadStream().pipe(out);
```

When dealing with file I/O alone, it's probably not a big deal because the file output *should* be faster than the data coming in over the network, but it's still good practice to use pipes where you can and avoid situations where you're listening directly to the 'data' event of an incoming stream.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for pointing out a path. The major issue here is that, the file that we are transferring is in s3 bucket and the params for iot.createStream is mentioned in original post. We are just referring to s3key to create Stream. In this case, how do I split the files? Sorry if this sounds silly but I am a noob when it comes to Nodejs or IoT! I believe I cannot store multiple files in s3 and pass them all in multiple stream for single OTA update. If not, then can you show me a path towards this?

Comment: If the file splitting path is even viable (this assumes you can re-assemble the file on the iot device), you'd have to split it up before it gets stored in s3. With that I can't help. Your other potential option (which, if viable, might make sense to add to the answer) would be to stream the file from s3 directly instead of through the iot stream. From the sounds of it, since these are just driver files, there may not be any benefit to retrieving the file through the iot module.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a even smaller size limit when you are more specifally using  OTA job from IoT Core jobs to update firmware, and that's **16MB**: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/amazon-freertos.html

FreeRTOS OTA Resource Quotas
| Resource  | Default |
| --------- | ------- |
| File size | 16MB    |

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34669475)